# Possible to achieve affect of overflow hidden without actually hiding the overflow?

Tags: css, overflow

I have an image slider which is positioned absolute and has a width of 1280px. The margin-left is -160px to center it in its parent. The parent width is 960px with margin set to '0 auto' to achieve a centered affect.

The image slider should only take up width:960px so that the overflow doesn't cause the browser to handle it with scrollers. Is it possible to achieve something like overflow:hidden while still showing the overflow content at high screen resolutions?

problem example: http://almightyidea.com/test/slider/

basic css:

```
.slide-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
 }

.slideshow{
    position:absolute !important;
    margin-left:-160px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use relative widths for the wrapper. So let it expand wider when the is room to do so. You could also use JavaScript to calculate the width of the viweport for you and set that width to the wrapper.

You could also just use an existing jQuery plugin to do all the heavy lifting. I use Cycle when I need to do stuff like this. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: I actually am using the cycle plugin for the slider. I am looking for a way for the wrapper to always occupy 960px centered in the browser with the rest of the image visible when the window width is greater then 960px